# Reading PHY MII registers beyond 0x1F

Tags: kernel-modules, ethernet

I am having some issues with a DP83826 PHY and therefore I want to read some configuration registers. I have used mdio-tool and mii-diag for it, but I just realized that I can only read the first 32 registers.

mii-diag -v (verbose) displays the first 32 registers (which might not be a coincidence) and if I use mdio-tool with an address beyond 0x1F, the address gets shifted to stay within the 0..1F range. I had a look at the code of mdio-tool and it does not limit the register address at all and I also hacked mii-diag -v a bit to get more than 32 registers and it also returns the first 32 registers again and again. So it seems that the limitation is somewhere else, but I have still not found where. I am now trying to find out if the API or the device driver is causing this issue.

I have also tried ethtool -d eth0 but it only dumps the GMAC and DMA registers.

How to read/writte PHY MII registers beyond 0x1F in Linux?

Comment: Not having any specific experience with this chip I can't say for sure, but it looks to me like you read those registers via the REGCR (0x0D) and ADDAR (0x0E) registers ... (see the datasheet [here](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/dp83826e.pdf))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out how it works:

The basic standard MDIO address consists of 5 bits and therefore only the [0..32] range can be accessed directly. For devices that offer additional registers beyond the basic standard, there is an MDIO
Manageable Device (MMD) indirect method (defined in IEEE 802.3ah draft for Clause 22) for accessing the extended register set.

In the end that is nothing else as an indirect access through a couple of registers in the base range. In my particular case (and as pointed by [@Murray Jensen](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/36176/murray-jensen)), REGCR (0x0D) and ADDAR (0x0E) are used for that purpose. The addresses and the bit fields within the registers may (and probably will) vary from one chip to another, but the mechanism should be rather similar.